# KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle not working

Tags: apex, knowledge

I'am trying to execute the following block which is supposed to create an article and publish it:

```
Test__kav testArticle = new Test__kav(Summary= 'Test', Type__c = 'Public', Language = 'en_US', Title = 'Test', UrlName = 'Test');
insert testArticle;

Test__kav k = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId, PublishStatus FROM Test__kav WHERE Id = :testArticle.Id];

String articleID = k.KnowledgeArticleId;
KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(articleID, true);

system.debug('PUBLISHSTATUS ' + k.PublishStatus);
```

The debug shows that the record is still in status 'Draft' after the publishing. There are no errors at all.

Any ideas what could be preventing the article from publishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article will have the `online` status (i.e. `published`).

The reason why you are getting a `draft` status, is because you are still retrieving the status that you fetched from the initial query.

After publishing, if you run the query it will show you `PUBLISHSTATUS = Online`

```
Rebate__kav testArticle = new Rebate__kav(Summary= 'Test', Language = 'en_US', Title = 'Test', UrlName = 'Test');
insert testArticle;

Rebate__kav k = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId, PublishStatus FROM Rebate__kav WHERE Id = :testArticle.Id];

String articleID = k.KnowledgeArticleId;
KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(articleID, true);

//execute this query below to retrieve the PublishStatus
k = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId, PublishStatus FROM Rebate__kav WHERE Id = :testArticle.Id];

system.debug('PUBLISHSTATUS ' + k.PublishStatus);
```